# COM Exception: 0x800702E4 in 3rd party DLL while accessing referenced dll function

Tags: c#, exception, com, wmi, elevated-privileges

I am facing this issue in a particular **window 8.1** OS. This is working fine in Window 7 and Window 10. Before this issue window 8.1 OS was having WMI corrupt issue, i have fix this WMI service and my other services is working fine but suddenly getting below error. **Is this due to WMI got repaired?**
**Error:**

```
2017-08-08 10:41:23,856 [12] ERROR ERDeviceControl.WACardioPerfectControl.WACardioPerfectControlClass [(null)] - Error while invoking _RunTest in  
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800702E4): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C54F9C85-7759-11D3-9464-002018805EC4} failed due to the following error: 800702e4 The requested operation requires elevation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800702E4).
   at ERDeviceControl.WACardioPerfectControl.WACardioPerfectControlClass.InitTest(ATestType aTT)
   at ERDeviceControl.WACardioPerfectControl.WACardioPerfectControlClass._RunTest()
```

Comment: 8 == fatal error, 7 == Windows error code, 0x2e4 == 740 == ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED, "The requested operation requires elevation".  That [takes you here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue in win 8.1. I have run my app as "Run as administrator".